# Random "Element is no longer attached to the DOM" StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I'm hoping it's just me, but Selenium Webdriver seems like a complete nightmare.  The Chrome webdriver is currently unusable, and the other drivers are quite unreliable, or so it seems.  I am battling many problems, but here is one.

Randomly, my tests will fail with a

```
"org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached 
to the DOM    
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64',
 os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_23'"
```

I'm using webdriver versions 2.0b3.  I have seen this happen with FF and IE drivers.  The only way I can prevent this is to add an actual call to `Thread.sleep` before the exception occurs.  That is a poor workaround though, so I'm hoping someone can point out an error on my part that will make this all better.

Comment: Hopefully the 17k views indicates that it's not just you ;) This has got to be the most frustrating Selenium exception out there.

Comment: 48k now! I have the same problem...

Comment: I'm finding that Selenium is pure and complete garbage....

Comment: 60k, still an issue :)

Comment: in my case it was because of doing `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException`

Comment: 123k and still counting! Believe it or not, StaleElementReferenceException is still an issue in 2022...

Comment: 125k and still counting. You are not alone Ray!

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Yes, if you're having problems with StaleElementReferenceExceptions it's because there is a race condition. Consider the following scenario:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
// DOM changes - page is refreshed, or element is removed and re-added
element.click();
```

Now at the point where you're clicking the element, the element reference is no longer valid. It's close to impossible for WebDriver to make a good guess about all the cases where this might happen - so it throws up its hands and gives control to you, who as the test/app author should know exactly what may or may not happen. What you want to do is explicitly wait until the DOM is in a state where you know things won't change. For example, using a WebDriverWait to wait for a specific element to exist:

```
// times out after 5 seconds
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    
// while the following loop runs, the DOM changes - 
// page is refreshed, or element is removed and re-added
wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("container-element")));        

// now we're good - let's click the element
driver.findElement(By.id("foo")).click();
```

The presenceOfElementLocated() method would look something like this:

```
private static Function<WebDriver,WebElement> presenceOfElementLocated(final By locator) {
    return new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        @Override
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.findElement(locator);
        }
    };
}
```

You're quite right about the current Chrome driver being quite unstable, and you'll be happy to hear that the Selenium trunk has a rewritten Chrome driver, where most of the implementation was done by the Chromium developers as part of their tree.

PS. Alternatively, instead of waiting explicitly like in the example above, you can enable implicit waits - this way WebDriver will always loop up until the specified timeout waiting for the element to become present:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

In my experience though, explicitly waiting is always more reliable.

Comment: Am I right in saying that it's no longer possible to read elements into variables and re-use them? Because I have a huge dry and dynamic WATiR DSL that relies on passing elements and I'm trying to port to webdriver, but I'm having the same problem. Essentially I'll have to add code to re-read all elements in the module for every test step that alters the DOM...

Comment: hi. May I ask what type Function is in this example? I can't seem to find it.... THANKS!

Comment: @Hannibal: `com.google.common.base.Function<F, T>`, provided by [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Comment: @jarib, I am facing this same issue one year since your solution. the problem is I am writing my scripts in ruby, and there is no function by the name of 'presenceOfElementLocated' or anything similar. ANy recommendations?

Comment: An extension to the above solution: The presenceOfElementLocated method is only helpful if you want to look up the presence but if you require to interact with the web element it should be visible, there's helpful method for that purpose called visibilityOfElementLocated

Comment: @jarib I disagree this is all caused by poorly designed test. Because even after the element appears after a AJAX call there may be jQuery code still running that could cause the StaleElementReferenceException. And the there is nothing you can do except adding explicit wait which doesn't seem very nice. I rather think this is a design flaw in WebDriver

Comment: @amey, you could catch this exception and just wait explicitly for a while before retrying the code that triggered it.
For instance, [like this](http://pastebin.com/fCZdrzxH).

I know you asked it a long time ago, but it may be useful for other folks that are looking for a solution.

Comment: This is not a flaw in webdriver.. if you feel you must 'blame' someone blame the ajax standards such as they are, or the browser..  it has no way to tell test code 'I'm busy doing javascript stuff that will update the page contents at any moment.   The most webdriver gets is when the browser has gotten the final stuff from the initial request from the server.  great for web 1.0, but for web 2.0  YOU need to know your client side code and how to tell when a page is 'ready' for the test to interact with it.

Comment: you should use `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)` instead `presenceOfElementLocated()`

Comment: @jarib what would recomend for a web page that is refreshing at an almost constant rate. In my case the DOM is destroyed and recreated multiple times per second as live data is being read from a physical medium. In this case the DOM always ends up in the same state for every refresh, but I still get Stale Element even when using all the different tips and tricks.

Answer (score 10):

I have been able to use a method like this with some success:

```
WebElement getStaleElemById(String id) {
    try {
        return driver.findElement(By.id(id));
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        System.out.println("Attempting to recover from StaleElementReferenceException ...");
        return getStaleElemById(id);
    }
}
```

Yes, it just keeps polling the element until it's no longer considered stale (fresh?). Doesn't really get to the root of the problem, but I've found that the WebDriver can be rather picky about throwing this exception -- sometimes I get it, and sometimes I don't. Or it could be that the DOM really is changing.

So I don't quite agree with the answer above that this necessarily indicates a poorly-written test. I've got it on fresh pages which I have not interacted with in any way. I think there is some flakiness in either how the DOM is represented, or in what WebDriver considers to be stale.

Comment: You have a bug in this code, you should not keep recursively calling the method without some sort of cap or you'll blow your stack.

Comment: I think it is better to add a counter or something, so when we are getting the error repeatedly, we can actually throw the error. Otherwise if there is actually an error, you will end up in a loop

Comment: I agree that it's not the result of poorly written tests.  There's a tendency for Selenium to do this on modern websites, even for the best-written tests -- probably because the websites are continuously refreshing their elements via the two-way bindings that are common in reactive web app frameworks, even when no changes to those elements need to be made.  A method like this should be a part of every Selenium framework that tests a modern web app.

Answer (score 10):

I get this error sometimes when AJAX updates are midway.  Capybara appears to be pretty smart about waiting for DOM changes (see [Why wait_until was removed from Capybara](http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara)
), but the default wait time of 2 seconds was simply not enough in my case.  Changed in _spec_helper.rb_ with e.g.

```
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5
```

Comment: This also fixed my problem: I was getting a StaleElementReferenceError and increasing the Capybara.default_max_wait_time solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem today and made up a wrapper class, which checks before every method if the element reference is still valid. My solution to retrive the element is pretty simple so i thought i'd just share it.

```
private void setElementLocator()
{
    this.locatorVariable = "selenium_" + DateTimeMethods.GetTime().ToString();
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)this.driver).ExecuteScript(locatorVariable + " = arguments[0];", this.element);
}

private void RetrieveElement()
{
    this.element = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)this.driver).ExecuteScript("return " + locatorVariable);
}
```

You see i "locate" or rather save the element in a global js variable and retrieve the element if needed. If the page gets reloaded this reference will not work anymore. But as long as only changes are made to doom the reference stays. And that should do the job in most cases.

Also it avoids re-searching the element.

John

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and mine was caused by an old selenium version. I cannot update to a newer version due to development environment. The problem is caused by HTMLUnitWebElement.switchFocusToThisIfNeeded(). When you navigate to a new page it might happen that the element you clicked on the old page is the `oldActiveElement` (see below). Selenium tries to get context from the old element and fails. That's why they built a try catch in future releases.

Code from selenium-htmlunit-driver version < 2.23.0:

```
private void switchFocusToThisIfNeeded() {
    HtmlUnitWebElement oldActiveElement =
        ((HtmlUnitWebElement)parent.switchTo().activeElement());

    boolean jsEnabled = parent.isJavascriptEnabled();
    boolean oldActiveEqualsCurrent = oldActiveElement.equals(this);
    boolean isBody = oldActiveElement.getTagName().toLowerCase().equals("body");
    if (jsEnabled &&
        !oldActiveEqualsCurrent &&
        !isBody) {
      oldActiveElement.element.blur();
      element.focus();
    }
}
```

Code from selenium-htmlunit-driver version >= 2.23.0:

```
private void switchFocusToThisIfNeeded() {
    HtmlUnitWebElement oldActiveElement =
        ((HtmlUnitWebElement)parent.switchTo().activeElement());

    boolean jsEnabled = parent.isJavascriptEnabled();
    boolean oldActiveEqualsCurrent = oldActiveElement.equals(this);
    try {
        boolean isBody = oldActiveElement.getTagName().toLowerCase().equals("body");
        if (jsEnabled &&
            !oldActiveEqualsCurrent &&
            !isBody) {
        oldActiveElement.element.blur();
        }
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex) {
      // old element has gone, do nothing
    }
    element.focus();
}
```

Without updating to 2.23.0 or newer you can just give any element on the page focus. I just used `element.click()` for example.

Comment: Wow... This was a really obscure find, nice work.. I'm now wondering if other drivers (eg chromedriver) have similar issues too

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to me when trying to send_keys to a search input box - that has autoupdate depending on what you type in. As mentioned by Eero, this can happen if your element does some Ajax updated while you are typing in your text inside the input element. The solution is to **send one character at a time and search again for the input element**. (Ex. in ruby shown below)

```
def send_keys_eachchar(webdriver, elem_locator, text_to_send)
  text_to_send.each_char do |char|
    input_elem = webdriver.find_element(elem_locator)
    input_elem.send_keys(char)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @jarib's answer, I have made several extension methods which help eliminate the race condition.

Here is my setup:

I have a class Called "Driver.cs". It contains a static class full of extension methods for the driver and other useful static functions.

For elements I commonly need to retrieve, I create an extension method like the following:

```
public static IWebElement SpecificElementToGet(this IWebDriver driver) {
    return driver.FindElement(By.SomeSelector("SelectorText"));
}
```

This allows you to retrieve that element from any test class with the code:

```
driver.SpecificElementToGet();
```

Now, if this results in a `StaleElementReferenceException`, I have the following static method in my driver class:

```
public static void WaitForDisplayed(Func<IWebElement> getWebElement, int timeOut)
{
    for (int second = 0; ; second++)
    {
        if (second >= timeOut) Assert.Fail("timeout");
        try
        {
            if (getWebElement().Displayed) break;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

This function's first parameter is any function which returns an IWebElement object. The second parameter is a timeout in seconds (the code for the timeout was copied from the Selenium IDE for FireFox). The code can be used to avoid the stale element exception the following way:

```
MyTestDriver.WaitForDisplayed(driver.SpecificElementToGet,5);
```

The above code will call `driver.SpecificElementToGet().Displayed` until `driver.SpecificElementToGet()` throws no exceptions and `.Displayed` evaluates to `true` and 5 seconds have not passed. After 5 seconds, the test will fail.

On the flip side, to wait for an element to not be present, you can use the following function the same way:

```
public static void WaitForNotPresent(Func<IWebElement> getWebElement, int timeOut) {
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= timeOut) Assert.Fail("timeout");
            try
            {
                if (!getWebElement().Displayed) break;
            }
            catch (ElementNotVisibleException) { break; }
            catch (NoSuchElementException) { break; }
            catch (StaleElementReferenceException) { break; }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found convenient approach to handle StaleElementReferenceException.
Usually you have to write wrappers for every WebElement method to retry actions, which is frustrating and wastes lots of time.

Adding this code

```
webDriverWait.until((webDriver1) -> (((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete")));

if ((Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return window.jQuery != undefined")) {
    webDriverWait.until((webDriver1) -> (((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0")));
}
```

before every WebElement action can increase stability of your tests but you still can get StaleElementReferenceException from time to time.

So this is what I came up with (using AspectJ):

```
package path.to.your.aspects;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

@Aspect
public class WebElementAspect {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(WebElementAspect.class);
    /**
     * Get your WebDriver instance from some kind of manager
     */
    private WebDriver webDriver = DriverManager.getWebDriver();
    private WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);

    /**
     * This will intercept execution of all methods from WebElement interface
     */
    @Pointcut("execution(* org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.*(..))")
    public void webElementMethods() {}

    /**
     * @Around annotation means that you can insert additional logic
     * before and after execution of the method
     */
    @Around("webElementMethods()")
    public Object webElementHandler(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        /**
         * Waiting until JavaScript and jQuery complete their stuff
         */
        waitUntilPageIsLoaded();

        /**
         * Getting WebElement instance, method, arguments
         */
        WebElement webElement = (WebElement) joinPoint.getThis();
        Method method = ((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();

        /**
         * Do some logging if you feel like it
         */
        String methodName = method.getName();

        if (methodName.contains("click")) {
            LOG.info("Clicking on " + getBy(webElement));
        } else if (methodName.contains("select")) {
            LOG.info("Selecting from " + getBy(webElement));
        } else if (methodName.contains("sendKeys")) {
            LOG.info("Entering " + args[0].toString() + " into " + getBy(webElement));
        }

        try {
            /**
             * Executing WebElement method
             */
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex) {
            LOG.debug("Intercepted StaleElementReferenceException");

            /**
             * Refreshing WebElement
             * You can use implementation from this blog
             * http://www.sahajamit.com/post/mystery-of-stale-element-reference-exception/
             * but remove staleness check in the beginning (if(!isElementStale(elem))), because we already caught exception
             * and it will result in an endless loop
             */
            webElement = StaleElementUtil.refreshElement(webElement);

            /**
             * Executing method once again on the refreshed WebElement and returning result
             */
            return method.invoke(webElement, args);
        }
    }

    private void waitUntilPageIsLoaded() {
        webDriverWait.until((webDriver1) -> (((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete")));

        if ((Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return window.jQuery != undefined")) {
            webDriverWait.until((webDriver1) -> (((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0")));
        }
    }

    private static String getBy(WebElement webElement) {
        try {
            if (webElement instanceof RemoteWebElement) {
                try {
                    Field foundBy = webElement.getClass().getDeclaredField("foundBy");
                    foundBy.setAccessible(true);
                    return (String) foundBy.get(webElement);
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                LocatingElementHandler handler = (LocatingElementHandler) Proxy.getInvocationHandler(webElement);

                Field locatorField = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("locator");
                locatorField.setAccessible(true);

                DefaultElementLocator locator = (DefaultElementLocator) locatorField.get(handler);

                Field byField = locator.getClass().getDeclaredField("by");
                byField.setAccessible(true);

                return byField.get(locator).toString();
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

To enable this aspect create file 
`src\main\resources\META-INF\aop-ajc.xml` 
and write

```
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="path.to.your.aspects.WebElementAspect"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Add this to your `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.1</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
</build>
```

And thats all. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using explicit wait so that you don't have to use hard wait.

If you fetching all the elements with one property and iterating through it using for each loop you can use wait inside the loop like this,

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements("Object property");
for(WebElement element:elements)
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy("Object property"));
    element.click();//or any other action
}
```

or for single element you can use below code,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy("Your object property"));
driver.findElement("Your object property").click();//or anyother action
```

Answer (score -1):

In Java 8 you can use very [simple method](http://blog.alvarus.org/2014/08/selenium-and-dynamic-web-applications-once-again/) for that:

```
private Object retryUntilAttached(Supplier<Object> callable) {
    try {
        return callable.get();
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        log.warn("\tTrying once again");
        return retryUntilAttached(callable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
FirefoxDriver _driver = new FirefoxDriver();

// create webdriverwait
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

// create flag/checker
bool result = false;

// wait for the element.
IWebElement elem = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("Element_ID")));

do
{
    try
    {
        // let the driver look for the element again.
        elem = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("Element_ID"));

        // do your actions.
        elem.SendKeys("text");

        // it will throw an exception if the element is not in the dom or not
        // found but if it didn't, our result will be changed to true.
        result = !result;
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
} while (result != true); // this will continue to look for the element until
                          // it ends throwing exception.
```

Comment: I added it just now after figuring it out. sorry for the format this is my first time to post. Just trying to help. If you find it useful, please share it to others :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)

Comment: Running the code above you may stuck in the loop forever, if for example there is a server error on that page.