# GhostDriver throwing stale exception "Element does not exist in cache" when executing javascript on existing element

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, wait, ghostdriver

---

Having problems with stale exception, GhostDriver is bubbling something was changed sice last execution.
On this {[Random “Element is no longer attached to the DOM” StaleElementReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709204/random-element-is-no-longer-attached-to-the-dom-staleelementreferenceexception)} question, that have more than 16k views, someone is telling about race conditions and things changing on test time but my code execute so fast that i cant believe something was changed.
Im changing nothing, all code execute fast, maybe the page itself is changing on the small time frame of test fragment execution.
The `myLibWorks.findElements(..` is ok and returning elements, its using `FluentWait<SearchContext>` then the element is available when method return.
It throws:

> Element does not exist in cache

after when i try execute javascript on element.
Here is the simplified fragment of my Java code:

```
by = getBy_A001();  
List<WebElement> welCollecN1 = myLibWorks.findElements(driver, timeOutInSeconds, pollingForSecond, by);  
if (welCollecN1 != null) {  
    WebElement wel01 = welCollecN1.iterator().next();  
    if(wel01 != null)  
    {  
        by = getBy_A002();  
        List<WebElement> welCollecN2 = myLibWorks.findElements(wel01, timeOutInSeconds, pollingForSecond, by);  
        if (welCollecN2 != null) {  
            WebElement wel02 = welCollecN2.iterator().next();  
            if(wel02 != null)  
            {  
                String value = null;  
                value = elm.getText();  
                if(value.length() == 0) {  
                    //-------------------------------------------------  
                    // REACH here then i think its ok above, this works almost of time too  
                    // THIS line throws "Element does not exist in cache"  
                    value = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(driver, "return arguments[0].innerHTML", wel02);   // <<== ERROR  
                    //-------------------------------------------------  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

---

> Element does not exist in cache   caused by Request =>
>   {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   image/png","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"84","Content-Type":"application/json;
>   charset=utf-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:4444"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"args\":[{\"ELEMENT\":\":wdc:1371656598440\"}],\"script\":\"return
>   arguments[0].innerHTML\"}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/efc7cf60-d8f6-11e2-9f07-192e7e451712/execute"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 736 milliseconds For documentation on
>   this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html Build
>   info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09
>   17:22:56' System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version:
>   '3.8.0-19-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_21' Session ID:
>   efc7cf60-d8f6-11e2-9f07-192e7e451712 Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Capabilities
>   [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=false, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   browserName=phantomjs, rotatable=false, driverVersion=1.0.3,
>   locationContextEnabled=false, version=1.9.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=false,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy={proxyType=direct},
>   nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=false, driverName=ghostdriver,
>   applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]} =======

---

The error looks bubbling from here : https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/source/browse/src/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/deps.js?r=78d90641df12d10b1f30b2bb4c08b92d6aff5f9b

```
/**  
 * Retrieves an element from the cache. Will verify that the element is
 * still attached to the DOM before returning.
 * @param {string} key The element's key in the cache.
 * @param {Document=} opt_doc The document whose cache to retrieve the element
 *     from. Defaults to the current document.
 * @return {Element|Window} The cached element.
 */
bot.inject.cache.getElement = function(key, opt_doc) {
  key = decodeURIComponent(key);
  var doc = opt_doc || document;
  var cache = bot.inject.cache.getCache_(doc);
  if (!goog.object.containsKey(cache, key)) {
    // Throw STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE instead of NO_SUCH_ELEMENT since the
    // key may have been defined by a prior document's cache.
    throw new bot.Error(bot.ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE,
        'Element does not exist in cache');
  }

  var el = cache[key];

  // If this is a Window check if it's closed
  if (goog.object.containsKey(el, 'setInterval')) {
    if (el.closed) {
      delete cache[key];
      throw new bot.Error(bot.ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_WINDOW,
          'Window has been closed.');
    }
    return el;
  }

  // Make sure the element is still attached to the DOM before returning.
  var node = el;
  while (node) {
    if (node == doc.documentElement) {
      return el;
    }
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  delete cache[key];
  throw new bot.Error(bot.ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE,
      'Element is no longer attached to the DOM');
};
```

---

Comment: My guess would be that you were waiting for the appearance of an iframe, then using that reference to get it's inner HTML. This might be related to https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1969 , seeing PhantomJS also uses Webdriver like Chrome does. In Chrome the Chromedriver was changed to prevent it happening only recently.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when including GhostDriver dependency and running tests with Chrome Driver. Adding this two addtional dependencies to the pom.xml solved the problem:

```

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

```

Don't forget to replace the selenium version with the one you are using.

Hope it helps!