# How to verify the dependent drop down values?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

There are two dropdown (A and B).
Values in the dropdown B is based on the value selected in Dropdown A.

How to verify values populated into the dropdown B for every value selected in dropdown A?

Comment: Take a look 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184055/selenium-select-value-from-a-drop-down-which-is-dependent-on-value-selected-in

Answer (score 0):

Just simulate the click action for dropdown A. Now compare the size of the number of li/option tag in dropdown B with the expected number. If they are equal then you can compare the contents inside by traversing through each li/option tag.